# Rigged model rotates and deforms when applying Auto Weights

Tags: rigging, weight-painting, rigify

When using Rigify as my armature my model falls over and scales up along with deforming when applying auto weights. I seem to get this result consistently when I practice rigging a character, what could be causing this?

[image]

Comment: Apply rotation and scale on both mesh and armature before parenting.

Comment: Yes, I have just tried that with no luck. I've clear all transformations and applied all transformations.

Comment: maybe share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/